# Unable to find ::before css selector element in selenium webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I want to test for checkbox checked or unchecked condition.

This is the html code for checkbox checked

```
<div classs="input-control checkbox">
<span class="check">
::before
</span>
</div>
```

`::before` is css selector.

when i hoverover to checkbox, it shows webelement as `span.check::before`

but

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("span.check::before"));
```

throws element not found exception.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You say you have a `::before` pseudo-element but your selector says `::after`...? (I'm not sure you can even find pseudo-elements.)

Comment: Why do you even need to target a pseudo element?

Comment: `div.checkbox::after` is *not* `span.check::before`. Every element can have separate `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have removed the pseudo-element `::before` from the CSS selector as seen below and it works

## **Instead of:**

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.check::before"))).build().perform();
```

## **I gave:**

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.check"))).build().perform();
```

Using pseudo-elements in the selector is actually not supposed to work as mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector#Usage_notes) and [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#grammar).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your exact html as the comment mentions there is no `::after` in your example html.  Based on your description this seems similar to the below, but not sure if that is what your exact situation is.

I have utilized the mouse move and then wait for the element that displays the modified css/class. The mouse would move and hover to the first element and then wait for the second to appear on the screen.  This works similarly for click and then wait for element to appear.

Hover code example - needs to match your code language and structure...

```
[Actions Instance goes here].MoveToElement([IWebElementGoesHere]).Perform();
```

you can also just do

```
[Actions Instance].Click([IWebElementGoesHere]).Perform();
```

Reference for this library: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AdvancedUserInteractions

Comment: Thanks all. yeah, it was typo error from my side.i put wrong webelement in findElement statement. it was supposed to be driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("span.check::before"));

Comment: Also, i found out that pseudo element are not supported by selenium css selector. In above case chrome generates the ::before pseudo element, where as firefox doesn't change the DOM at all. no pseudo element was created.

Answer (score -1):

I have faced similar issue with pseudo css selectors (::before alike), I have overcome the issue using "Actions" class of selenium java.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[id$='save-button']"))).build().perform();
```

Hope it helps.

Thanks,
Sampath

Comment: Does that second line of code actually select the `::before` element?