# Unable to locate element "::before" for click

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

How to locate an element **::before** for click.

Below is the HTML:

`<i class="icon-add-circle" tabindex="0" >
             ::before 
</i>`

Comment: You can look into this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288358/unable-to-find-before-css-selector-element-in-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 0):

Dear friend you can try below snippet .

```
   driver.findElement(By.className("icon-add-circle"));
```

Answer (score 0):

To locate the element you can use the following line of code :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//i[@class='icon-add-circle']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//i[contains(@class,'icon-add-circle')]"));
```

Above code of line should do. Also try to locate from the parent element always and drill down to the child element.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

Get all elements of i tag

```
1) driver.findElement(By.xpath("//i[@class='icon-add-circle']/*"));
```

Get text of all elements under i tag

```
2) driver.findElement(By.xpath("//i[@class='icon-add-circle']//text()"));
```

Get single element. Specify correct array index.

```
3) driver.findElement(By.xpath("//i[@class='icon-add-circle']/*[1]"));
```